# Data Binding to the Table error is not a fucntion

Tags: sapui5

I have problem with binding the OData to the table. When i define a function in js file it says "is not a function"

odata.js

```
getBoM : function(iNumber){


        var sNumber = iNumber.toString();
        while (sNumber.length < 18) {
            sNumber = "0" + sNumber
        }


        var vUriRead = "/ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM";
        var oResult;

        this.initODataModel( );

        this.oDataModel.read(vUriRead, null, null, false, function(oData, oResponse) {
            oResult = oData;
        }, function(oError) {
              jQuery.sap.log.error("OData-Error in function getBoM (EntityBoMSet)");
              xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.displayRequestFailedMessage(oError);
        });

        return oResult;
    },
```

Controller.js

```
var oProductHead2BoM = xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.getBoM(iNumber);

        this.oModelProductHead2BoM.setData(oProductHead2BoM);
```

at the .getBoM(iNumber) it says, "Uncaught TypeError: xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.getBoM is not a function"

Edit : 
controller.js

```
handleRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "page") {
        var iNumber = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").number;

        var oDataResult = xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata
                .getDetailsProd(iNumber);
        this.oModelProdManag.setData(oDataResult);

        var aDocuments = xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.getDocumentsProd(iNumber);

        this.oModelDocuments.setData(aDocuments);

        //Call bom routine and set data

        var oProductHead2BoM = xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.getProductHead2BOM(iNumber);

        this.oModelProductHead2BoM.setData(oProductHead2BoM);
```

So when i debug and click on function ".getDocumentsProd" i can find the function which is reference to odata.js

Odata.js

getDocumentsProd Function

```
getDocumentsProd : function(iNumber){

        var sNumber = iNumber.toString();
        while (sNumber.length < 18) {
            sNumber = "0" + sNumber
        }
        var vUriRead = "/DocumentsSet/?$filter=Material%20eq%20'" + sNumber + "'";

        var oResult;

        this.initODataModel( );
        this.oDataModel.read(vUriRead, null, null, false, function(oData, oResponse) {
            oResult = oData.results;
        }, function(oError) {
              jQuery.sap.log.error("OData-Error in function getDocumentsProd (EntityDocumentsSet)");
              xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.displayRequestFailedMessage(oError);
        });

        return oResult;

    },
```

On the same note i have for the getProductHead2BOM function.

```
getProductHead2BOM : function(iNumber){

        var sNumber = iNumber.toString();
        while (sNumber.length < 18) {
            sNumber = "0" + sNumber
        }


        var vUriRead = "/ProductHeadSet('5199182')/ProductHead2BOM";
        var oResult;

        this.initODataModel( );

        this.oDataModel.read(vUriRead, null, null, false, function(oData, oResponse) {
            oResult = oData;
        }, function(oError) {
              jQuery.sap.log.error("OData-Error in function getProductHead2BOM (EntityProductHead2BOM)");
              zplm_homepage.zplm_homepage.src.odata.displayRequestFailedMessage(oError);
        });

        return oResult;
    }
```

I could see documents Odata but not for ProductsHeadBom

[image]

Comment: Can you share the fine structure and more code of the affected files?

Comment: Problem is that i don't see the function on sources(chrome) though it exists in IDE.

Comment: You must import it somewhere to be able to use it.

Comment: use the require part of the controler to import the js file in which you function is

Comment: why is the part titled with view.XML still js code? i am confused

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I debug with the console, i have attached the screenshot of the debug.